# Trying to install Ruby 3.2.2 but keep getting error during installation

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

Please bear with me as this is my first time coding with Ruby, but I've been trying to install it for a while now but each time I keep getting the following error. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this? I am currently on MacOS Ventura. [picture of the error message in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVNjH.png)

Comment: You should probably read the mentioned file... Also, please don't post screenshots of code or error messages in your question. Add the actual text instead.

Comment: Rails 3 is unlikely to run properly on Ruby 3.2.2. Why are you running such an old and unsupported Rails version?

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many things to install ruby 3.2.2 with rvm but I was getting the below issue

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j12'
```

But after trying different things, I found something which really made my day. Try with below :

```
xcode-select --install
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 3.2.2 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!